# Azure account email forgotten

Tags: azure

A few months ago I created a Microsoft account for Azure services. I got an API key for an Android app, I updated the app recently and the API key is working fine. The thing is I wanted to check my account and I realized **I had forgotten my MS account.** 
I've tried to check in my other email providers if I received some emails from that account, any password recovery or anything like that, but... nothing. The only thing I have is the API key stored in my app's server.

Is there any way I can recover my account?

Thank you.

Comment: This is something only Azure Support can assist with. Unfortunately not something that can be resolved on Stack Overflow (as it's not programming-related, and is specific to subscription service access). You can open a billing ticket (free to do) and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

That is insufficient to recover the account. You should contact Azure support and give your name and details (KYC) and they will be able to get you back in.